# Instance of array property in generic class?

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I have a generic class of typescript with 2 properties as -

```
export class WrapperModel<T>{
    constructor(private testType: new () => T) {
        this.getNew();
    }

    getNew(): T {
        return new this.testType();
    }
    public Entity: T;
    public ShowLoading: boolean;
}
```

Then using it as follows -

```
this.userModel = new WrapperModel<UserProfileModel>(UserProfileModel);
```

I am assuming it is creating an instance of type `UserProfileModel` in its constructor.

But when I try with Array type property then it fails. Like when I do -

```
this.userModel = new WrapperModel<Array<UserProfileModel>>(Array<UserProfileModel>);
```

The error which I get in above case -

[image]

Is it I cannot create an instance of Array property in generics or something else.
My need is simple; I want to create instance of `Array` properties in Generic class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that that at runtime generics are erased, so `Array<UserProfileModel>` is not really a constructor function, `Array` is the constructor function so you can write:

```
var userModel = new WrapperModel<Array<UserProfileModel>>(Array);
```

This applies for any generic type, not just array:

```
class Generic<T> {  }
var other = new WrapperModel<Generic<UserProfileModel>>(Generic);
```

Generally for a generic class there does not appear to be a way to get a constructor for specific type instantiation, only the generic constructor:

```
// Valid, new get a generic constrcutor
var genericCtor: new <T>() => Generic<T> = Generic;

// Not valid,  Generic<UserProfileModel> is not callable
var genericCtor: new () => Generic<UserProfileModel> = Generic<UserProfileModel>;
```

Comment: It worked thanks. Is it only pass `typeof` argument for all generic types?

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand the question

Comment: I meant to say what if I pass only type of argument as - `this.userModel = new WrapperModel<UserProfileModel>(object)` <-- `object` is passed

since the type argument is removed right?

Comment: You have to pass the class without generic arguments, that does not mean any generic class would too, typescript still checks compatibility, so this will give an error: `class Generic<T> { public foo: number }
class Generic2<T> { public foo2: number }
var other = new WrapperModel<Generic<UserProfileModel>>(Generic2);`